# Permission for reading System.in in java

Tags: java, security

I have some code which is reading user input from console using below code.

```
Console console = System.console();
String input = console.readLine();
```

However, this code should run in a very secure env, where every action's permissions are controlled through a policy file.

So I did my testing of the java code with policy file as

```
grant codeBase "file:/myjar.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I have no clue, what permission I should use to grant permission to `console.readLine()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `System.console` in a JVM with the `SecurityManager` enabled, you'll need the following RuntimePermissions:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "readFileDescriptor";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "writeFileDescriptor";
```

**Why?**

The `System.in` and `System.out` file descriptors (0 and 1, with 2 representing `System.err`) are already open to the JVM. The `SecurityManager` verifies that you have write access to the open file descriptors through the [`checkWrite(FileDescriptor fd)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkWrite%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29), and similarly that you have read access through the [`checkRead(FileDescriptor fd)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkRead%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29). The `RuntimePermission` required by those methods are listed in the javadocs.

While the "writeFileDescriptor" might appear superfluous, it is necessary for initializing the Console object (atleast in the Oracle Java 7 runtime).